# python json dumps puts object into object on row_to_json return

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I am running a Postgres query in python which returns me an array of JSON objects.

```
    db = SQLDB('postgres://postgres:*****@localhost:5433/postgres', migrate=False)
    q = ("SELECT row_to_json(t) FROM (SELECT * FROM fn_drivetime_eu_grid_" + request.get_vars.country + "_coord(" + request.get_vars.x + ", " + request.get_vars.y + ", " + request.get_vars.sec + ")) t;")
    mySQL = db.executesql(q)
    return json.dumps(mySQL)
```

The problem is that the objects are inside objects. Dawg!

Not a big problem, but I would like to know whether there is a more elegant solution for this.

[image]

Comment: Show the Python code and the query output.

Comment: I extended the code sample.

Comment: Any chance we can see the raw JSON instead of whatever tool it's currently showing in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what happen if you dump the whole result set. With the `t` table:

```
create table t (a int, b text);
insert into t (a, b) values (1,'x'), (2,'y');
```

Using Psycopg2:

```
query = "select row_to_json(t) from t"
cursor.execute(query)
rs = cursor.fetchall()

# dump the whole result set
print json.dumps(rs)
print

# dump each column:
for r in rs:
    print json.dumps(r[0])
con.close()
```

Output:

```
[[{"a": 1, "b": "x"}], [{"a": 2, "b": "y"}]]

{"a": 1, "b": "x"}
{"a": 2, "b": "y"}
```